# radio button switches upon submission

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, selection

So when I select the radio button labeled black and click the add button to display the value, the radio button labeled red get selected and that value is displayed. Heres my code:

```js
function add() {
  var total;

  if (document.getElementById("btn").checked = true) {
    total = 0
  } else if (document.getElementById("2ndbtn").checked = true) {
    total = 1;
  } else {
    total = 0
  };

  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h5>what color is the car?</h5>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" id="btn" /> red
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" id="2ndbtn" /> black
  <button type="button" onclick="add();">add</button>
  <p id="show"></p>
  <script src="questions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this in your code:

```
if(document.getElementById("btn").checked = true){
total = 0
}else if(document.getElementById("2ndbtn").checked = true){
    total = 1;
}else{total = 0};
```

You are actually setting the checked value to true, and not checking if it is true. Therefore you will have to change it to this:

```
if(document.getElementById("btn").checked){
    total = 0
}else if(document.getElementById("2ndbtn").checked){
    total = 1;
}else{total = 0};
```

Then it should work.

Comment: wow thanks! I thought I tried it that way but obviously I did something wrong I appreciate your help it works just fine now!